# Split compoundcurve at specific vertices using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have two PostGIS tables which include geometries`:

```
CREATE TABLE compcurv
(
    f_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('fid_seq'::regclass), 
    myattr int,
    geom geometry(CompoundCurve,4326) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT compcurv_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fid))

CREATE TABLE pnts
(
    fid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('fid_seq'::regclass), 
    myattr int,
    geom geometry(Point,4326) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT compcurv_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fid))
```

I would now like to create a trigger function that splits my `compcurv` layer using my `pnts` layer after a change on either (All `pnts` features are vertices of a `compcurv` feature) and add the split compund curves to `compcurv`. I have tried ST_Split which does not work due to the circularstrings.

Comment: You would need to transform your `ST_CurveToLine` - it will conserve your curve vertices - and *vice versa*. However, it seems ambiguous, and tedious, to have triggers here, especially on changes to the vertex table. I'd suggest to only work with the vertices, and a set of positional identifiers to recreate curves - which is *much* easier to handle when applying changes (you'd only update the positional ids), and then have a *Materialized View* that constructs curves based on those ids; a refresh would make changes take effect automatically.